# some reading kref_kotlin troubles on C++ side, strange values in varables

Tags: kotlin-native

I've built the native kotlin library for Android Arm64 target, kotlin generated *.h and *.so. files, added these files to Android project and tried to create kref_values on c++ side by default h-file kotlin functions:

```
mylib_ExportedSymbols* symbols = mylib_symbols();
auto kdouble = symbols->createNullableDouble(12345678.88);
if (kdouble.pinned != nullptr) {
    auto val = *(static_cast<double*>)(kdouble.pinned);
    // val has strange value, and it diferents from 12345678.88
    std::cout << "double = " << val << std::endl;
}
```

kdouble has the type:

```
typedef struct {
   mylib_KNativePtr pinned;
} mylib_kref_kotlin_Double;
```

How to read this double if I don't have another appropriate functions in h-file to extract double value from mylib_kref_kotlin_Double type?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, @Andrei! Could you please extend the question with the definition of createNullableDouble(..) fun? AFAIK, all functions returning Double in Kotlin should return `<libname>_Double`, not `<libname>_kref_kotlin_Double`.

Comment: My bad, I just found a `createNullableDouble` is in the library default API. The most straighforward idea I got is to make a function fun getDouble(input: Double?): Double = input ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("input was null").

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev These functions in h-file:  

typedef struct {
  /* Service functions. */
  void (*DisposeStablePointer)(mylib_KNativePtr ptr);
  void (*DisposeString)(const char* string);
  mylib_KBoolean (*IsInstance)(mylib_KNativePtr ref, const mylib_KType* type);
  // .....
  mylib_kref_kotlin_Long (*createNullableLong)(mylib_KLong);
  mylib_kref_kotlin_Float (*createNullableFloat)(mylib_KFloat);
  mylib_kref_kotlin_Double (*createNullableDouble)(mylib_KDouble);
  mylib_kref_kotlin_Char (*createNullableChar)(mylib_KChar);
.....
}

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev I understood your work-around, but this approach is not good to me, cause it confuse a little, I need  a better solution: it should works without any work-arounds. Could you, pls, patch current kotlin version to fix this issue?

Comment: Please move this discussion to kotl.in/issue, it begins to over the StackOverflow format as we discuss a compiler modification rather than answering a question.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev done. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newissue?project=kt&draftId=25-3002419